# Problem with Random number generation in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

The code releases the first element of "wait", and randomly assigns the element to a service (simulator or gym), if there is space available in the service, based on certain conditions.

If a random number has been generated but it does not lead to a valid service, the code generates a new random number up to 100 times before breaking out of the loop.

```
if (wait.size() > 1 && (simulators.size() < 6 || Gym.size() < 15)) {
// Free the current wait and pick a service at random
wait.free(wait.get(0));
Random rand = new Random();
int iterations = 0;

while (true) {
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt(2) + 1; 
    if (randomNum == 1 && simulators.size() < 6) {
        // Choose the simulator service if there's space available
        wait.get(0).var_simulatorService = true;
        break;
    } else if (randomNum == 2 && Gym.size() < 15 && wait.get(0).par_allowForGym == true) {
        // Choose the gym service if there's space available
        wait.get(0).var_Gym = true;
        traceln("The agent number " + wait.get(0)+ " Alllow to go Gym - " + wait.get(0).par_allowForGym);
        break;
    } else {
        // generate a new random number if the previous one didn't lead to a valid service
        iterations++;
        if (iterations >= 100) {
            traceln("The agent number " + wait.get(0)+ " Alllow to go Gym - " + wait.get(0).par_allowForGym);
            break;
        }
    }
}}
```

[image]

On the basis of this code when `wait.get(0).par_allowForGym == false` then the loop will run(100 times) unless the random value become 1, but based on this error that never happen and loop break.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your model is not breaking because of the code but because of the `SelectOutput` setup. An agent is forced to leave via the last exit at the bottom but there is nowhere for it to go.

Either connect a process flow to that exit node or ensure in the `SelectOutput` logic that agents can never leave via the last exit.